# git :open(" "): no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code

When I try to commit my changed I get this error : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwR6c.png).
I need to mention I just created a new repo for this project so it is the firm commit I ever do in it.
This code takes a file and turns it into a .pdf document. I enabled git in the Vs code settings so I don't think I did something wrong.

My code:

```
const convertapi = require('convertapi')('api');
const path = `./FilesToBeConverted/`;
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');


    

    
    

const rl = readline.createInterface({
input : process.stdin,
output : process.stdout
});

var completed_path = "";
var file_name = "";
var file_ext_in = "";
var file_ext_ult = ".pdf";
var path_without_ext = '';
var final_path = "";
var finp = "";

var toate_nume = [100];

var i = 0;

let temp = fs.readdirSync(path);

temp.forEach((f) => {
  file_name = f;
})

final_path = path + file_name;

conv();

function conv(){
  convertapi.convert('pdf', { File: final_path })
    .then(function(result) {
      // get converted file url
  

      console.log("Converted file url: " + result.file.url);

  
      finp = path + file_name.slice(0, file_name.length - 5) + ".pdf";
      console.log(finp);

      // save to file
      return result.file.save(finp);
    })
    .then(function(file) {
      console.log("File saved: " + file);
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.log("numele si/sau extensia fisierului sunt gresite");

      process.exit(1);
  });
}
```

Comment: If you are using command-line Git: what *command* did you run? (The source file itself is not very interesting.)

Answer (score 0):

So There was an nameless empty file created in the local repo I wanted to push to GitHub, that I couldn't delete. I could open it in vs code and I deleted all the chars inside that file and renamed it. I deleted it normally and now I can push my repo